# Unable to place more than 1 item on pivot c# WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, pivot

I'm stuck with not being able to display random generated numbers on a pivot page. Below is my code,

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Height="768" Width="480">
        <!--Pivot Control-->
        <phone:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION" Loaded="Pivot_Loaded">           

            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="Stats">                   
                <Border
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}" Background="Black">
                    <Grid Margin="-3,75,-17,-75">

                        <TextBlock
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="10,121,253,422" FontSize="30" Text="Highest Temp : " />
                        <TextBlock
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="10,0,253,551" Text="Current Temp :" FontSize="30" />
                        <TextBlock
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="10,240,253,311" Text="Lowest Temp : " FontSize="30" />
                        <TextBlock
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="10,360,253,191" Text="Average Temp : " FontSize="30" />
                        <TextBlock Name="TempAverage"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="222,360,41,191" Text="-" FontSize="30" />
                        <TextBlock Name="TempLowest"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="222,240,41,311" Text="-" FontSize="30" />
                        <TextBlock Name="TempHighest"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="222,121,41,430" Text="-" FontSize="30" />
                       <TextBlock Name="TempCurrent"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="222,0,41,551" Text="-" FontSize="30" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

            </phone:PivotItem>
```

It then tells me the error "The name 'TempAverage does not exist in the current context'. Same with TempCurrent, TempHighest and TempLowest. What is the error that I am facing and how should I go about it?

```
int a = 0;
void time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer time = new DispatcherTimer();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    double TempRandom = rnd.Next(100, 500); //generate random number
    double TempRandom2 = TempRandom / 10;

    ***TempCurrent.Text = TempRandom2.ToString("0.0");

    if(TempRandom2 > Max) 
    {
        Max = TempRandom2; //Highest Temp = Current Temp
        TempHighest.Text = Max.ToString("0.0"); 
    }

    if(TempRandom2 < Min)
    {
        Min = TempRandom2;
        TempLowest.Text = Min.ToString("0.0"); //Lowest Temp = Current Temp
    }

    AvgTemp[a++ % 100] = TempRandom2;
    if (a > 100)
        TempAverage.Text = AvgTemp.Average().ToString("0.0");
    else
        TempAverage.Text = (AvgTemp.Sum() / a).ToString("0.0");***
}
```

Comment: That's because you've defined the `Text` property within the xaml itself.

Comment: What do you mean? How should I change my code so that I can get the value in?

Comment: I mean you have given a value like this in xaml 
Text="-" Just take it off and see. Because you can't assign two things to the same control at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a name to your elements. Eg. `TextBlocks. When you add a name to the elements you can reference them in the code. Like this.

```
<TextBlock Name="TempCurrent"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
           Margin="10,0,253,551"
           Text="Current Temp :" 
           FontSize="30" />
```

Comment: Yes, but to reference the TextBox in the code you need to add a name to it.. Did you try the code in the answer?

Comment: try Setting TempCurrent.Text = "Test Value"; this will work in your code.

Comment: can you tell me exactly what line u r getting the error?

Comment: Which if? u have 3. 3rd?

Comment: TempCurrent.Text, TempHighest.Text, TempLowest.Text and TempAverage.Text are all the underlined errors when I try to run the prg

Comment: Can you tell me where you define the timer_tick event handler?